# Position: relative; causing the element to overlap everything

Tags: css, position

I've made something like this:
Check this image
[image: avatar]

To achieve I did create a `div` with height, width, relative position and put the image and the on-hover text, inside with

```css
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
left: 0; 
right: 0;
```

everything works great, but the problem is,
As I'm using position relative on the parent

So, this div overlaps everything, like my sticky header, modals and stuff.
check this screenshot
[image: avatar]

I tried manually giving higher `z-index` to my header, modals. which solves the problem, but I think it could get really complicated over time :(

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Seems like you helped yourself. This is exactly how to use `z-index` to solve such problems and it can indeed get messy to keep track of everything if you have a lot of `sticky` or `fixed` content. Alternatively, you can also use negative a `z-index` so that your `div` will stay underneath without affecting the stacking behaviour of your other content.

Comment: I tried giving -1 `z-index` to the `relative` `div` but it gets completely hidden, as it goes underneath whole document, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this achieves what you want, I didn't have a chance to test it, but it should solve the problem of the image being absolute and thus overlapped over the nav.

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
    <img src='#' alt=''>
    <div class='overlay'>
        <div class='hover-txt'>Upload new image</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 200px; /*you can set the width that you need*/
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 200px;
}

.container img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover; /*keeps the image ratio*/
    border-radius: 200px;
}

.container .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.container .overlay .hover-txt {
    display: none;
    color: white;
}

.container:hover .overlay .hover-txt {
    display: block;
}
```